# Embedded iframe not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an embedded iframe supplied by another company for an event registration.

https://casaimports.com/food-expo/attendee-registration/

No matter what I try I cannot get the iframe to scroll using the mouse scroll wheel. If you have your cursor on the form it won't scroll. If the cursor is off the iframe, near the scrollbar then it works.

The original code supplied did not have an overflow style set. I added it and have tried overflow:scroll and overflow:auto but to no avail.

Here is the full code that was given to me:

```js
var userOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var safariLink = document.getElementById("safari-link");
var iFrame = document.getElementById("iframeResizer0");
if (/safari/.test(uagent) && !/chrome/.test(uagent)) {
  safariLink.style.display = "inline";
  safariLink.setAttribute('href', safariLink.getAttribute('href') + '&Offset=' + userOffset);
  iFrame.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("iframe-loading").style.display = "none";
} else {
  safariLink.style.display = "none";
  iFrame.style.display = "inline";
  iFrame.setAttribute('src', iFrame.getAttribute('src') + '&Offset=' + userOffset);
}
iFrameResize({
  autoResize: false,
  log: true, // Enable console logging
  enablePublicMethods: true, // Enable methods within iframe hosted page
  checkOrigin: false,
  resizedCallback: function(messageData) { // Callback fn when resize is received
    document.getElementById("iframe-loading").style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#iframe-loading {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://tradeshow.perenso.net/registration/scripts/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<div id="iframe-loading"><img src="https://tradeshow.perenso.net/registration/content/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>

<iframe src="https://tradeshow.perenso.net/registration/embedded/index/CASAIMPORTSSEP18?RegType=CUSTOMER" style="border: 0; width: 100%; overflow:auto;" id="iframeResizer0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>

<div style="text-align: center;">

  <a href="https://tradeshow.perenso.net/registration/embedded/index/CASAIMPORTSSEP18?RegType=CUSTOMER" id="safari-link" target="_blank" class="button icon icon-after fa-chevron-right">Open Registration Form</a></li>


</div>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Any luck handling the scroll issue on iframe ??

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `scrolling="yes"` attribute to your `<iframe>` tag in the **HTML**. Like this:

```
<iframe src="https://tradeshow.perenso.net/registration/embedded/index/CASAIMPORTSSEP18?RegType=CUSTOMER" style="border: 0; width: 100%; overflow:auto;" id="iframeResizer0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I tried that also, but it still doesn't scroll. I just added it to the code to double check, but still not scrolling.

Comment: Hi @Mike I'm away from my desktop currently, will message when I'm back.

Answer (score 3):

your iframe element needs the `scrolling="yes"` attribute...

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I tried that also, but it still doesn't scroll. I just added it to the code to double check, but still not scrolling.

Comment: Either a hardware problem, or the iframe has a overflow:hidden css rule within the child document.

Comment: This does not work in HTML 5

Answer (score 0):

If you have used either `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` in somewhere in your style sheet inside child window/embedded iFrame better to remove them and add alternatives through a media query for iOS Safari. having values for both of them are not supported by iOS Safari. Refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#browser_compatibility)